# Is there any plugin in Jenkins for distributing unit tests to slave machines in parallel fashion and returning back the results to the master?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, plugins, continuous-integration

Is there any plugin in Jenkins for distributing unit tests to slave machines in parallel fashion and returning back the results to the master? The plugin should work in a agent-less manner or agent based manner.

Comment: Why this non-sense edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Parallel Test Executor Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parallel-test-executor) for this. It splits up all your test based on the previous run's JUnit XML files and distributes them among a defined number of subtasks.

P.S: I recently wrote a [blog article](https://www.emnify.com/2017/09/18/emnify-automated-testing-on-jenkins/) about how we use this plugin in our environment.

Comment: Does it distribute the unit tests to slave machines as well and return the results back to the master node?    for ex i intend to distribute runs of my tests on multiple machines. 
For eg, i have a test suite of 10,000 tests. I have 100 test machines and hence if i could divide these 10,000 tests among 100 machines

Comment: This should be possible, have a look at the pipeline code in the blog article. What the plugin actually does is that it splits up the list of tests (based on their runtime). These splits are then written to include/exclude lists which then can be applied inside the allocation of an executor.

Comment: And yes, all results are merged afterwards.